# Extracting substring before alphabet in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the following strings contained in column1:

```
1) 12345BC01
2) 67890DE05
```

How can I formulate my SELECT clause to extract only the values before any alphabet character? So my output would look like:

```
1) 12345
2) 67890
```

I found the following solution, but it seems to grab everything AFTER the alphabet characters:

```
SELECT STUFF(column1,1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',column1),0)-1,0),'')
```

I wish I could detail what else I've tried but I don't know the first thing about regex unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to just use the *left* function and isnull the result if there are only numbers

```
select IsNull(Left(Col1, NullIf(PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', col1), 0)-1), col1)
from t;
```

Comment: I was able to make sense of this solution, so I am accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
Select left(column1,patindex( '%[^0-9]%', column1+'A')-1)
 from @YourTable
```